# Representing complex objects in a Python enum

Tags: python, enums, spyder

I am working with a graph-based framework that consists of several types of nodes and relations. Each of these types has some meta-properties that I would like to be able to access easily. To represent these types, I figured that an enum would be the way to go.

I'm still relatively new to Python, but I know enums from other languages like Java. I guess this question really comes down to whether this is a good use of enums in Python. I'm representing my types like this:

```
class Grammar(Enum):
    VERB = 'verb'
    NOUN = 'noun'
# END Grammar

class _Word():
    def __init__(self, name, meta):
        self.name = name
        self.meta = meta
    # END __init__
# END _Word

class Word(Enum):
    TYPE_A = _Word('foo', Grammar.VERB)
    TYPE_B = _Word('bar', Grammar.NOUN)
# END Word
```

So each of my Word values is assigned a _Word object, which is a complex type. This works fine in most cases where the Enum is used. However, my colleagues noted that Spyder throws an exception when inspecting an object in which an instance of the enum is present: `ValueError():  is not a valid Word` (note the blank space after the colon).

This makes me think that the way I'm using the enum is not the best practice. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hard to say without understanding exactly what you are trying to accomplish. I have never see Enums used to keep track of any set of relationships more complicated than simple bookkeeping. Enums weren't even a language feature until Python3.4 so the language clearly wasn't designed with them as being a necessary construct, but more added for convenience. What relationships are you trying to capture exactly?

Comment: I think it is a valid representation, however, you probably need to ask yourself why you need to access the meta-properties of the types, if the framework API does not enable it... maybe you are not using the framework as intended, or, maybe you should not use one?

Comment: I'm trying to capture the semantics of my graph framework. As an example, think of the nodes as words and the graph as a sentence. For each of my words, I would like to know its definition, e.g. whether it is a verb or a noun. Since the semantics of the framework should not change over time, I figured modeling it as enum constants made a lot of sense.

Edit: By framework I do not mean a python library, but rather a set of rules on how you can use the node and relations types (a grammar if you will)

Comment: @thijsfranck:  Could you redo your example with the verb/noun/grammer style instead of the a/b/foo/bar style?  It's hard to see what you are actually trying to accomplish with generic names.

Comment: That's a good point. I changed my example!

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to have been that several libraries like pandas and json have a hard time serializing enum objects. I found several solutions online that explain how to write a custom serializer. However, since I cannot tell Spyder or Pandas to use that serializer, I needed something different.

After playing around a bit more, I have found two approaches that solved my problem. Unfortunately, the solution using Enums does not work with Python 2.7 which is a requirement for my project. Thus, I will explain both.

**Python 3.4:**

I added the data types of my values as a mixin for my Enum class and annotate the assignment of my enum values as suggested [here](http://hultner.se/quickbits/2018-03-12-python-json-serializable-enum.html). Specifically for use with dataframes, I also needed to make my enum objects comparable, which I did by defining comparison methods. Finally pass the Enum values into the constructor for my complex objects. This removes the need to access the properties via the value attribute.

```
class Grammar(str, Enum):
    VERB: str = 'verb'
    NOUN: str = 'noun'

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return not self < other and not other < self
    # END __eq__

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self < other or other < self
    # END __ne__

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return other < self
    # END __gt__

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return not self < other
    # END __ge__

    def __le__(self, other):
        return not other < self
    # END __le__

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value < other.value
    # END __lt__

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.value)
    # END __hash__
# END Grammar

class _Word(dict):
    def __init__(self, name, meta):
        self['name'] = name
        self['meta'] = meta
    # END __init__
# END _Word

class Word(dict, Enum):
    TYPE_A: dict = _Word('foo', Grammar.VERB)
    TYPE_B: dict = _Word('bar', Grammar.NOUN)

    def __init__(self, _word):
        self['name'] = _word['name']
        self['meta'] = _['meta']
    # END __init__

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return not self < other and not other < self
    # END __eq__

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self < other or other < self
    # END __ne__

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return other < self
    # END __gt__

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return not self < other
    # END __ge__

    def __le__(self, other):
        return not other < self
    # END __le__

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self['name'] < other['name']
    # END __lt__

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self['name'])
    # END __hash__
# END Word
```

This allowed Spyder to handle my enum without any problems. As a bonus, when using the object with a dataframe or when serializing as json, the generic object representations are now replaced with the actual values. This makes life very easy!

**Python 2.7:**
Unfortunately, the Enum implementation for Python 2.7 does not carry over all the syntax that is required to make my first solution work. Specifically, the `VERB: str = 'verb'` annotated assignment is not allowed. I ended up removing the use of Enums and switching to class attributes instead. This still allows for access in a way that makes clear that you're dealing with a constant (e.g. `Grammar.VERB`), but does mean that you lose the nice-to-have Enum features.

The most important thing for me was to be able to iterate over my enum values, so I made a function that allows me to retrieve all the values from my pseudo-enum:

```
class PseudoEnum():

    @classmethod
    def getAll(cls):

        """
        Returns a list of tuples representing all entries for this PseudoEnum along the dimensions key x value. This is useful when you need to iterate over the enum.

        :returns: A list of all PseudoEnum entries
        :rtype: list of tuple
        """

        return [(i, getattr(cls, i)) for i in dir(cls) if not i.startswith('__') and not callable((getattr(cls, i)))]
    # END getAll        
# END PseudoEnum
```

`Grammar` and `Word` now inherit from `PseudoEnum`. Further, the comparison methods have moved from `Word` to `_Word`. `Grammar` no longer needs the comparison methods since it deals with regular strings.

Apologies for the longwinded answer. Hope this helps!